# What are all the names shown on the Marauders Map in the third Harry Potter movie where Fred and George give Harry the map?

Tags: harry-potter

What are all the names shown on the Marauders Map in the scene where Fred and George give the map to Harry in the third Harry Potter movie?

The writing was too small for me to work them out.

Answer (score 3):

We see the map briefly twice in close-up during [that scene.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNc43oKqQzg)
Those names that can be read clearly are:

[image]
**Albus Dumbledore.**

[image]
**Newt Scamander.**

[image]
**Lara Blishen.**

[image]
**Alistair Ballcocke** (in two different places at the same time).

[image]
**Antonia Creaseworthy** (in three different places at the same time).

[image]
**Mordicus Egg** (in two different places at the same time).

[image]
**Almeda Peidus** (in two different places at the same time).

[image]
**Bathilda Bagshot** (in two different places at the same time).

What's *most* intriguing isn't the fact that several people seem to be there repeatedly, although that's pretty damned lazy on the part of the filmmakers, but the fact that several of those people (Antonia Creaseworthy and Mordicus Egg, for example) are **actually dead and yet still walking around**.